Mostrar el primer registro según condición en un Select
Tengo una tabla carta y quiero mostrar los campos cod - int(10) y fec_mov - date. Pero quiero mostrar el fec_mov mayor por cada código.
Con esta sentencia me muestra el listado:
SELECT cod, DATE_FORMAT(fec_mov,'%d/%m/%Y') as fec_mov
FROM carta
ORDER BY cod ASC, fec_mov DESC

Pero no me muestra ordenando por fec_mov de mayor a menor por cada código.
cod  fec_mov    
14  24/06/2003* 
14  15/10/2002  
39  19/11/2021  
39  02/10/2023* 
39  01/03/2023  
43  28/02/2022  
43  27/09/2024* 
43  23/05/2003  
43  21/09/2001  
43  13/02/2023  
67  26/01/2004  
67  14/10/2014* 
67  07/05/2003  

El resultado que quiero es:
cod  fec_mov    
14  24/06/2003  
39  02/10/2023  
43  27/09/2024  
67  14/10/2014  

Que muestre cada código con el campo fec_mov que tenga la fecha mayor.
Intenté usar max(fec_mov) pero solo muestra un único registro.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Primero que nada, mantenemos lo que tienes primero, esto es correcto es la información que queremos mostrar.
SELECT cod, DATE_FORMAT(fec_mov,'%d/%m/%Y') as fec_mov
FROM carta

Segundo, procedemos a realizar una simple query, de la cual obtendremos los datos esperados (los mismos que antes), pero con la condición que has impuesto (el max de cada cod)
SELECT cod, MAX(fec_mov) AS max_fec_mov
FROM carta
GROUP BY cod

Una vez verificada que esta consulta obtiene los datos que queremos, procedemos a unirlas con un JOIN. Y acá lo importante, son las condiciones para unirlas. Mantenemos el cod, pero además, solo las que sean igual a la fecha máxima.
INNER JOIN ( ... ) subquery
ON c.cod = subquery.cod 
AND c.fec_mov = subquery.max_fec_mov

Y finalmente la consulta completa se ordena por cod, y quedaría de este modo aprox.
SELECT c.cod, DATE_FORMAT(c.fec_mov, '%d/%m/%Y') AS fec_mov
FROM carta c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT cod, MAX(fec_mov) AS max_fec_mov
    FROM carta
    GROUP BY cod
) subquery
ON c.cod = subquery.cod AND c.fec_mov = subquery.max_fec_mov
ORDER BY c.cod ASC;

Esto debiese darte algo como lo esperado abajo. Si no resulta, necesitaré que muestres la tabla con más datos para ver que falta considerar.

No hace falta complicarse tanto, podes usar las funciones de agregación y formato al mismo tiempo. Demo.
